# how to shutdown tomcat windows service within 30 seconds (or ask more time from SCM)

Tags: windows, tomcat, service, timeout, shutdown

I have problem with my tomcat launched as windows service. There are few web applications running on it, and when I attempt to stop service (programmatically) it takes more than 30 seconds to stop it and SCM aborts operation due to the time limitation (default is 30 seconds). This can be configured in registry, but I am not able to change it (and seems to be ugly solution). How can I solve this? Is there some kill_timeout for tomcat? Or how should I stop my applications?

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat config GUI (AKA The Apache *"Commons Daemon Service Manager"*) has a `Shutdown` tab (Tip: open `tomcatw.exe` in your installation path). Here you will see a `Timeout` value. This might solve your problem.

[image: Screenshot of tomcatw.exe | Shutdown | Timeout]

It is also explained in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Command_line_parameters:

> `ParameterName`   *Default*   Description
>   [...]
>   `--StopTimeout`   *No Timeout*    Defines the timeout in seconds that procrun waits for service to exit gracefully.

Alternatively, check this: [Tomcat doesn't stop. How can I debug this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971876/tomcat-doesnt-stop-how-can-i-debug-this)